# Installing VB6 runtime on Server 2008 x64

Tags: c#, windows, dll, vb6

I have moved all my users from windows 7 machines to Windows Server 2008 remote desktop.  All of the apps they use currently were developed in vb6 (new apps are being developed in c#.Net currently) and need to be used for the time being...

The apps seems to run fine in Windows 7.  I just can't get them to play nice with server 2008.  I did try to run dependency walker and found it was missing "msvbvm60.dll".  Tracked that down to the actual VB6 runtime.  Tried to find a download for VB6 runtime for server 2008 x64 and that was a no go.  So I just tried to put the "msvbvm60.dll" file inside c:\windows\system32\ and c:\windows\SysWOW64.

It said there was already a file named "msvbvm60.dll" in the SysWow64 folder.  So my question is, why would it not work?  It seems windows 2008 already has the runtime on the machine.  But depends says that "msvbvm60.dll" is missing... :/

Ideas?

Comment: Interesting... we have 50+ users in server 2008 running a VB6 ActiveX DLL... no issues other than, well the code is a mess!

Comment: @retailcoder more then likly they included the depends in the install file.

Comment: Doesn't server 2008 have win7 under the hood? It has to be something's missing in your installer... I think.

Comment: All very valid statements but as it stands, when I run the same installer on any Windows 7 machine the application works perfectly fine.  Furthermore I have to point out again the reason the application will not run after installing on Server 2008.  The file missing is "msvbvm60.dll", a standard vb6 runtime...   This is not a special file I need to include in my application this is a file all vb6 apps are built on.  ;)

Comment: Have you tried this download? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290887

Comment: Yea tried that too.  I download it then extract it, then run the "vbrun60sp6.exe" file and it looks to do nothing...  Starts some type of extracting then just dies...  On the download page I found this (no mention of server 2008)... Supported Operating System
Windows 2000, Windows 2000 Advanced Server, Windows 2000 Server, Windows 2000 Service Pack 2, Windows 2000 Service Pack 3, Windows 2000 Service Pack 4, Windows 95, Windows 98, Windows 98 Second Edition, Windows ME, Windows NT, Windows Server 2003, Windows XP

Comment: Hmm... my sincere sympathies, I'm out of ideas! Best of luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

**The issue has to do with DEP!**

*The root cause of this problem is a change made in Windows Server 2008 R2 to the time when the tsappcmp.dll module (Remote Desktop Services Application Compatibility DLL) gets initialized, which consequently causes your application to call DLL functions before it establishes a link to functions within the DLL.*

The way I solved it was very simple!  I just excluded my application from the Data Execution Prevention process and it allowed the application and all it's dependencies to load up without faulting in a timely manner.

Usage:

```
rundll32 sysdm.cpl, NoExecuteAddFileOptOutList "FullPathToExecutable"
```

Example:

```
rundll32 sysdm.cpl, NoExecuteAddFileOptOutList "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApplication\MyApplication.exe"
```

---

Sources:

- [Access Violation of BEX or APPCRASH occurrs on Windows Server 2008 R2 with Terminal Service](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2279689)

Answer (score 1):

This is a wild guess but can you run them with Compatibility Mode? (right-click > Properties > Compatibility)

Comment: Tried that and none of the OSs would work...  :l  First thing i tried.